# React Interval not stopping after Leaving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have the problem that the interval I am using in `useEffect` isn't stopping when leaving the component.

The code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      refreshSave();
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
```

I am thinking about animating an empty `span` and then using `onAnimationIteration` to trigger the save.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clean up setInterval in useEffect using react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763957/how-to-clean-up-setinterval-in-useeffect-using-react-hooks)

Comment: If you kill your dev server, clear cache/hard reload the browser tab/window, and restart the local dev server does the issue persist? I don't see anything wrong with your code, but I have seen where intervals were setup and persisted by the browser during "intermittent" save/hot reloads.

Comment: What does "leaving the component" means, show us reproducible code [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If the quoted answer of @ShahnawazHossan doesn't help you, I think a combination of clearInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) and a return statement in useEffect to simulate componentWillUnmount (https://dev.to/robmarshall/how-to-use-componentwillunmount-with-functional-components-in-react-2a5g) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really give us much of a context to work with (e.g. what do you mean by "leave the component"?), so we're kinda shooting in the dark.

However, as a first step, you *could* try declaring the `timer` variable ***globally***:

```
let timer;     // <- put here
useEffect(() => {
    timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      refreshSave();
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue before, solved it by using the `useRef` hook.

```js
const funRef = useRef(null);

//...

useEffect(() => {
    funRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      refreshSave();
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
     clearInterval(funRef.current);
    };
  }, []);
```

for more: [timer app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371873/unable-to-clear-setinterval-in-react-native-app)